# BIRT Viewer Reporting Error

Tags: database, postgresql, birt

I have recently installed BIRT Viewer Version : 2.6.1 in tomcat on a CentOs Linux machine. We initially thought we had successfully installed it, as our reports were working fine. However we are now recieving a error message, which we are unable to solve. We are extracting data from a postgresql database and have put the drivers in the correct location. The error message we get when trying to run the reports is the following:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
```

With the following stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1096)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1316)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:282)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:85)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1307)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/core/v3/Portal
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1720)
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:466)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doExecuteQuery(OdaQuery.java:464)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.executeQuery(OdaQuery.java:428)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:575)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:806)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:427)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1094)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:232)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:172)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.(QueryResultSet.java:98)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:80)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.executeQueries(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:205)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.execute(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedItemExecutor.execute(ExtendedItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:258)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:260)
... 50 more
```

We also got the following error in our log file:

```
Jan 26, 2011 5:39:09 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask doRun
SEVERE: Error happened while running the report.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/core/v3/Portal
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1720)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:466)
 at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doExecuteQuery(OdaQuery.java:464)
 at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.executeQuery(OdaQuery.java:428)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:575)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:806)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1094)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:232)
 at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.executeQueries(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:205)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.execute(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedItemExecutor.execute(ExtendedItemExecutor.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:260)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:85)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1307)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
 at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
 at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
 at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
 at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The log file seems to suggest that postgresql is unable to locate a class, however we have the file in the correct location.

Can anyone provide any insights or help?

Thanks

Comment: What location exactly is a "correct location" and what file exactly  you have put as the postgresql driver? Is that report working in Report Designer?

Comment: The report is working in the report designer and the postgresql driver is in the location:
birt-viewer\WEB-INF\platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc\drivers.
The file is the postgresql driver.

Comment: The file is: postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 4):

Try to put JDBC driver in one of

- `lib` directory of your application server (tomcat/lib or sth appropriate to your server)
- `birt-viewer/WEB-INF/lib`

You'll be more sure the driver is available on a JVM classpath.

Comment: We tried this and restarted tomcat. It worked for about a day, but now we have the same problem again.